# Can a redstone latch in Bedrock Edition be supplemented with a toggle function?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

SR latches and T-flip-flops are trivial circuitry in Minecraft redstone, but it appears that there is little to be found for a circuit that combines both, allowing for both SR and T functionality.

I envision an SR-T latch to have set, reset, and toggle inputs respectively, but all connected to the same memory cell. This means that the output can be controlled by setting it, resetting it, *and* toggling it all at once. Just like an SR latch, pressing S or R when the cell is already in that state should do nothing.

All of my circuitry so far has been "unclean" implementations, either a bodged wiring to add a toggle to an SR latch, or bodged wiring to add SR inputs to a T-flip-flop. What is the best way to go about making such a latch?

**See also:** [Same question for Java Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/369842/250180) *(originally one question; separated upon request from others)*

Comment: Which game are you actually playing, MCJava or MCBE?

Comment: Since you are asking for *both* editions, it would best to split it into 2 questions - we aim for a 1:1 question to answer ratio - multiple questions can make it difficult to provide a good and specific answer - some users might be experienced in one and not the other, meaning that this question, as it is, requires 2 answers. There's nothing wrong with posting 2 questions about the same thing in different systems!

Comment: A 1:1 question to answer ratio is not at all the goal, having a valid answer for the entire question is the goal and only one question should be in a question post.

Comment: I don't know how you read that into my answer, but I just replied to the "1:1 ratio" thing in the previous comment, because multiple answers per question are usually a good thing. What you did is totally fine and good, no worries.

Comment: As I said: Everything is fine, no worries. By limiting this question, you made it a valid question here already. I don't know if you can see that, but there are 3 reopen votes on this already. 2 more and it gets reopened. This just takes a bit of time, because not many people here check questions with reopen votes.

Comment: I really don't understand why you're still confused. EVERYTHING IS FINE. You already asked a separate MCJava question! I'll try to get an answer to that when I have time, others can also answer in the meantime. There's nothing you need to do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary mechanism you're going to want is an RS latch and some AND gates. This will operate as a regular RS latch when you press the On or Off button, and as a Toggle when you press Toggle. This works by routing the toggle signal to the appropriate end of your RS latch, turning it on or off based on the current state of the RS latch

[image: Circuit diagram consisting of an RS latch and a pair of AND gates]

[I feel like I've been here before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/370063). Anyway. As it turns out there are quite a few differences in how Minecraft Bedrock Edition redstone works that I don't fully understand, which makes my Java Edition answer inoperative in Bedrock edition. However, with some small tweaking, it can be made to work.

The main tweak is a monostable circuit on the Toggle line:

[image: Input lines with monostable circuit]

This circuit uses a sticky piston to, in one game tick, send a redstone pulse and cut it off. This causes the Toggle input to only be on for 1 tick. This prevents the mechanism from cycling more than once when the toggle button is pressed. Without this, the pistons will switch back and forth repeatedly until the signal turns off, which is not what we want.

From here, only minor tweaks are required to the original Java mechanism (Bedrock edition has different rules about when redstone dust connects to pistons, so a few more redstone repeaters were required):

[image: RS Latch and AND gate mechanism]

As in my previous answer, there are sticky pistons underneath the gold blocks which act as AND gates, and a redstone repeater underneath the diamond block to keep the signal from the repeater on the Reset line from being directly connected to the Output line.

Unfortunately, due to the monostable circuit, this build is quite a bit bulkier in Bedrock edition, coming in at 9x4 on Bedrock (vs 5x4 on Java).

Comment: I want to keep developing this, I'm not happy with 9x4, so I'll take a look in a few alternate directions to get something that's both compact and functional in Bedrock Edition.

Comment: For I can accept this as the best answer. Please keep working on this and edit this post if you come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to make it, just put any STACKABLE item that stacks to 64 in the dropper. To toggle just power and unpower the piston[image: enter image description here, to toggle just power and unpower the piston]

Comment: How does this address the question?  The OP asked for three buttons, I'm only seeing two.  Also, if you hit a button on the dropper, where is it going to put the items?  Are the droppers pointed towards each other?  Not clear from the screen shot.

Comment: Unless redstone in MCBE is totally broken, this does not toggle the output state on a third button press.